# Python3.8 with PySide2 Class to Class Usage

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyside2

My GUI essentially wraps various backend PowerShell scripts that perform some automated functions. Kind of beside the point, but alright, here's where I'm stuck at.

I've got my interface designed in Qt Designer, outputted to a .ui file, converted to a .py file via PySide2-UIC, and a mainwindow class that is a subclass of the main window class I created in Qt Designer. All is well. No issues with any of that.

I'm now on to a part in my programming that I'm capturing form data from QWidgets (which is working) to a list. I've got a completely custom written class that is meant to handle taking that user input, setting other variables like filenames or paths to certain configuration files that are needed, and executing a subprocess PowerShell command with all of that information. Where I'm stuck at is trying to determine what the right place is to instantiate this custom object, inside my MainWindow class, outside my MainWindow class? But if so, where? Here's some simplified code to help explain my dilemma.

**Interface Sequence**

1. App start
2. MainWindow appears
3. User browses to form with input controls
4. User enters info like (IP address, username, password)
5. User clicks button that is connected to a method in the class
6. Method recurses through the child widgets on the page and captures info into a dictionary via finding qLabels and qLineEdit (buddies)

**Questions**:

- How do I call the next method (only once even though the capturing of data is recursive)? I'm thinking about just connecting the signal to a second method that handles taking the captured data and sending/setting it into the custom class object. However, when I instantiate my custom object inside of the MainWindow class and I try to reference the object by self.customObject.sendUsesrInput(self.userInputVariable), PyCharm doesn't think self is defined inside this particular method. It doesn't properly highlight the word "self" like in the rest of the class definition, and it suggests that I need to import self.

**Update**
I was able to clear the errors around "import self" in PyCharm. It had something to do with improper spaces vs. tabs, even though I only ever use the tab key to do indentation. Might need to go and check my inpection settings closer. The other questions still stand though. Where is the best place to call methods on my custom class to "form a command", and "run a command", should that be executed by the mainWindow class, or should I set a flag on the customObject class that then triggers those other actions? Or more generally, should an object be in charge of executing it's own functions/methods, something tells me not usually, but I can't be sure. Also, if there are any books on the matter, I'd be happy to do my own research. I'm currently reading "Rapid GUI Programming" but not sure if this topic is covered in the later chapters just yet.

- So I guess my question is, where do I handle the customObject class, in the mainWindow class, or in some other place? If so, where?

I apologize if this question is NOT clear. I promise to update as necessary to help work through this.

Here's come simplified code examples:

```python
class customClass(object): # this is actually in a separate file but for argv sake
   def __init__(self):
      self.userInput = ""
      self.file1 = ""
      self.file2 = ""
      self.otherstuff...

   def setUserInput(self, uinput):
      self.userInput = uinput

   def dostuffwithdata(self):
      # method to execute subprocess command


class MainWindow( QMainWindow ): 
   def __init__(self):
      super(MainWindow, self).__init__()
      self.ui = Ui_MainWindow()
      self.ui.setupUi(self)
      self.customObject = customClass.customCmdClass()
      self.cmddata = dict()
      self.ui.toolButton.clicked.connect(self.getformdata)

   def getformdata(self):
      # recurses through QWidgets and grabs QLabels and QLineEdit.Text() and updates dict()
      for w in widgets:
         if w is qlabel:
            k = w.text()
            v = w.buddy().text()
            self.cmddata.update({k: v})

   """ all the above works fine. what doesn't work is this part"""
   # at this point I want to send the collected data to the customObject for processing
   def senddatatocustomObject(self):
      self.customObject.setUserInput(self.cmddata)  """but this says that 'self' isn't defined. 
I know it has to be because of the object in an object, or something I'm doing wrong here.     
**Update**: figured this out. PyCharm was freaking out about some sort of  
perceived indentation error despite there not appearing to actually be one.   
Was able to correct this. """


if __name__ == '__main__':
   import sys

   app = QApplication(sys.argv)
   win = MainWindow()
   win.show()

   sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: improve your indentation in `__init__` method. When you say *Python doesn't think self is defined inside this particular method.*  What do you mean? be precise.

Comment: Updated the question as you have suggested. Thanks for the pointers.

Comment: You point out that line `self.asBuiltCmd.setUserInput(self.cmddata)` throws an exception but in your MRE I don't see that code

Comment: I was able to clear that error. It was indentation related (spaces vs tabs according to PyCharm) even though I only used tabs while writing the code. I'm sure my inspection settings are the culprit there. My bigger focus is just the best practice around where to call my customObject's methods from. Where should I build the logic in to grab the user input, send it to the cutomObject, execute methods on the custom object to grab filenames, and then finally formulate my PowerShell command and execute. Should I be calling all of those methods/actions from within my MainWindow class?

Comment: Is that the place you'd normally put that type of code when dealing with a GUI application, within the classes? It's not the same as procedural programming where the logic and methods are written in the main body/class of the code, right? This really comes down to a lack of experience with purely Object Oriented programming on my part, I'm sure.

Answer (score 0):

In an effort to close this out, I offer this answer to my previously posted question about where to put the "logic" and flow in my code.

Given that this is a graphical application without any back-end services, it makes the most sense to put most of the user-interaction logic and flow within the MainWindow object because that is essentially the control center of my program. When a user clicks or enters something, it is going to happen on the MainWindow, when a state changes, it happens (mostly) on the MainWindow or is directly tied to the MainWindow in some way. Therefore, it makes sense to include the majority of my method calls, user-input-flow logic, and other code, in the MainWindow class/object of my program.

My other classes and objects are there to capture state and to perform actions on different sets of data, but in most cases, these auxiliary classes/objects will/should be controlled by the MainWindow of my application.

This is certainly not the only way to write this application or others, but I believe this at least answers my previously posted question(s).